# Attempt to boot from the USB Stick returns to the UEFI again

Tags: boot, bios, desktop-computer, computer-building

I bought a brand new SSD and it's the only one which is attached to the PC right now. I am trying to boot my computer from the bootable USB stick which I created with a Windows 7 image However, after I select the boot device "UEFI: SanDisk Cruzer Fit 1.27" from the boot menu open up by pressing F8, instead of starting the Windows setup, after a few seconds of waiting, it returns back to the UEFI's start screen again.

I also disabled the Fast Boot, reset the keys for Secure Boot to the Defaults, and under as OS Type now selected "Windows UEFI".

How can I create a bootable USB and set up UEFI correctly to be able start the computer from the USB Stick?

Comment: My guess: the problem lies with the USB stick.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 7 doesn't support uefi. So you have to activate legacy boot in the bios settings. If you don't want to disable uefi and activate legacy there is a guide to create a uefi windows 7 I haven't tried it but I think it should be working.
https://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/321097-how-install-windows-7-uefi-mode-usb.html

Comment: Windows 7 absolutely does support UEFI it's just limited to the 64-bit versions of Windows 7.  This answer is also confusing.  You first say Windows 7 doesn't support UEFI but then link to a guide (which you haven't verified) which indicates not only does Windows 7 support it but how to install Windows 7 in UEFI only mode.  Of course there is a third major problem, you don't actually explain how to do anything, in the body of your answer.  So basically it's just an answer with a link.